# Invalid left-hand side in assignment, "this = xxx"

Tags: javascript, this

I want to add splice function into String, like Array's splice function. That's the code

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, len, substr) {
  var p = this.split('');
  p.splice(start, len, substr);
  this = p.join('');
  return this;
}
```

It will show

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't re-assign `this`. Try declaring a variable and using that:

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, len, substr) {
    var p = this.split('');
    p.splice(start, len, substr);
    var joinedArray = p.join('');
    return joinedArray;
}
```

`this` is a reference, not an object. It is what we would call "immutable".

Comment: But it will different from Array's splice function. `var p = [1,2,3,4]; p.splice(1,1);` Then p will be [1, 3, 4].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reassign `this` because `this` value by definition is immutable, you can't change in that way what it references to.

All you need to do is

replace

```
this = p.join(''); return this;
```

with

```
return p.join('');
```